# Could front-running be mitigated by placing the transaction fee data in the signed bytes?

Tags: transactions, frontrunning, mev

I'm very much learning. I've just discovered front-running and MEV (not the hard way, luckily).

My understanding is that the transactions are reordered based on cloning the transaction and sending it in with a higher fee?

If so, then why not put the gas fee data in the signed, serialized payload?

Obviously this cannot be done or won't help else they'd have done it, so I guess understanding why would further my understanding generally. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My understanding is that the transactions are reordered based on cloning the transaction and sending it in with a higher fee?

Not quite. In a traditional MEV sandwich (i.e. you send off a transaction to sell something on uniswap with max 10% slippage, so someone orders transactions around yours so they sell before you and buy after you sell) has nothing to do with the gas price/gas amount of the target transaction. The MEV doesn't need to (and can't!) change the gas price/amount of your transactions.

The fee data is already in the signed data, otherwise miners could just make you pay as much as they want.

Comment: Thank you, Nate. Perhaps there are a number of MEV strategies. My understanding came from https://www.paradigm.xyz/2020/08/ethereum-is-a-dark-forest in which the author's transaction was cloned with higher gas to outbid the original tran.

Comment: @LukePuplett Yes, MEV is regularly attained by taking someone elses transaction from the mempool and *doing it yourself* with a higher gas price. This is different than what you explained in your question, that gas should be part of signature so they can't alter it. But they aren't "altering" *your* transaction, they are simply creating their *own* transaction that would do the same thing yours is doing, but with a higher gas price